# WPF xaml dynamically adding checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I am new to WPF/xaml and am working on an application where checkboxes get added dynamically to the window. I have this functionality working, however there are some issues and I feel like there might be a better approach to this problem. I have looked into this and found a few different solutions, none of them seem to work. (CheckboxList, Panel)

Right now I am using a ListBox to hold my checkboxes -- I am wondering if there is a better solution for adding dynamic checkboxes.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.FileSelectionWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FileSelectionWindow" Height="368.917" Width="701.669">
    <Grid Margin="37,10,31.2,12.2">
        <Button Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,0,0,33.6" Name="specificZip" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="specificZip_Click">Zip</Button>
        <Button Height="21" Margin="0,0,173,33.6" Name="specificCopy" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Click="specificCopy_Click">Copy</Button>
       <ListBox Name="cbList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,60.6">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding test}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Height="2" Width="3" />
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you come across and tried to use the [`ItemsControl` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already?

Comment: Also, you are currently declaring a `ListBox` inside another `ListBox` - is that intentional?

Comment: I haven't seen that yet. Is that some sort of container?

Comment: Like I said, this is my first time trying this programming language.. I don't think I am doing two listboxes

Comment: it seems when I move the  `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding test}"` line to be in the same listbox declaration above it  the checkboxes dont show up.. not sure why that is

Comment: You have to look at the `ItemsControl` for sure. You can define your own template so it will generate for example a checkbox and some text for each list item.

Comment: I am looking into that now.. if I wanted to get the items that were checked off, how would I go about that? It seems like isSelected and isChecked dont work for itemsControl

Comment: What exactly do you provide via `test` (that's what your binding in the `ItemsSource` property points to)?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure what binding does.. I read about a solution online and when I tried it it made the text fields show up from the check boxes... I am almost 100% that I am not using `test` anywhere in my c# code

Comment: @KevinMee: Understanding bindings is crucial to using `ItemsControl` in a meaningful way. I suggest you first find some information on the topic of dependency properties and bindings (WPF has its peculiarities compared to other UI toolkits, so unfortunately it comes with a certain first step upon entering), that might already help you a lot understand how to solve this task.

Comment: I will look into that.. Thank you for all your advice